# Nested JSON arrays

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am parsing some JSON that has arrays within arrays, and I just cant seem to get the data of the arrays within the first array.

My JSON looks like this (I cut it off in the end so it wasn't that long):

```
{"TrackingInformationResponse": {
"shipments": [
{
  "shipmentId": "03015035146308",
  "uri": "\/ntt-service-rest\/api\/shipment\/03015035146308\/0",
  "assessedNumberOfItems": 1,
  "deliveryDate": "2013-05-13T11:47:00",
  "estimatedTimeOfArrival": "2013-05-13T16:00:00",
  "service": {
    "code": "88",
    "name": "DPD"
  },
  "consignor": {
    "name": "Webhallen Danmark ApS",
    "address": {
      "street1": "Elsa Brändströms Gata 52",
      "city": "HÄGERSTEN",
      "countryCode": "SWE",
      "country": "Sverige",
      "postCode": "12952"
    }
  },
  "consignee": {
    "name": "Lene Bjerre Kontor & IT Service",
    "address": {
      "street1": "Lene Bjerre",
      "street2": "Ørbækvej 8, Hoven",
      "city": "TARM",
      "countryCode": "???",
      "postCode": "6880"
    }
  },
  "statusText": {
    "header": "Forsendelsen er udleveret",
    "body": "Forsendelsen blev leveret 13-05-2013 kl. 11:47"
  },
  "status": "DELIVERED",
  "totalWeight": {
    "value": "0.55",
    "unit": "kg"
  },
  "totalVolume": {
    "value": "0.005",
    "unit": "m3"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "itemId": "03015035146308",
      "dropOffDate": "2013-05-08T17:18:00",
      "deliveryDate": "2013-05-13T11:47:00",
      "status": "DELIVERED",
      "statusText": {
        "header": "Forsendelsen er udleveret til modtageren",
        "body": "Forsendelsen blev udleveret  13-05-2013 kl. 11:47"
      },
```

I can get the content of the "shipments" array just fine, but I have no idea how to get the contents of the "items" array. My code looks like this:

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject TrackingInformationResponse = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("TrackingInformationResponse"));
            JSONArray shipments = new JSONArray(TrackingInformationResponse.getString("shipments"));

            for (int i = 0; i < shipments.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject JSONitems = shipments.getJSONObject(i);        
                String shipmentId = JSONitems.getString("shipmentId");

                //do stuff
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ReadWeatherJSONFeedTask", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
```

How would I do the same with the "items" array as I did with the "shipments" array?

Comment: the JSON is not complete!

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the `items` array from inside the Shipment array, like you did the shipments, then iterate through that, like you did the shipments.

It might look something like:

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject TrackingInformationResponse = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("TrackingInformationResponse"));
            JSONArray shipments = new JSONArray(TrackingInformationResponse.getString("shipments"));

            for (int i = 0; i < shipments.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject JSONitems = shipments.getJSONObject(i);        
                String shipmentId = JSONitems.getString("shipmentId");
                JSONArray items = new JSONArray(JSONitems.getString("items");
                 //get items stuff
                //do stuff
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ReadWeatherJSONFeedTask", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. But is there no other way of doing this? I have a lot of nested arrays, and if I have to make a for-loop for each, it gets quite messy.

Comment: You could put the JSON into a `hashmap` and iterate over the `hashmap` using a while loop; but, you're still going to have to iterate over the set to get all the values out of each array object. You could also create a recursive function to pull out the nested arrays, but, again, you're still going to have to iterate over the array.

Answer (score 0):

`items` is a JSON Array located **inside** the `shipments` array, so you need to get the `items` array within the `shipments`, maybe like this :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < shipments.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject JSONitems = shipments.getJSONObject(i);        
            String shipmentId = JSONitems.getString("shipmentId");
            JSONArray items = new JSONArray(JSONitems.getString("items"));
            //iterate over items
        }
```

Hope this helps, Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow code:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(yourJSONString);
JSONObject trackInfo = jObject.getJSONObject("TrackingInformationResponse");
JSONArray shipMents = trackInfo.getJSONArray("shipments");
JSONArray items = shipMents.getJSONArray("items");
```